# Rewrite Client Facing URL with Tomcat Rewrite Valve

Tags: apache, tomcat, url-rewriting

I currently have a rewrite.config file with the following: RewriteRule ^/abc /docs.  This successfully directs clients to the docs webapp, but I would still like the client to see localhost/abc in their browser.

In Apache mod_rewrite, this would be handled by simply adding [PT] to the end of the rewrite rule.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Brandon

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the Tuckey [UrLRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/). It appears to have better documentation and offer more flexibility than Tomcat's Rewrite value.